# Limiting the number of characters recognized by tesseract OCR

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, masking

[The images I'm trying to mask look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX41h.jpg) I'm using tesseract as a library to iterate through multiple images and identify the numbers on them and then mask the numbers. I've got 12 digits in every image and I want it to stop identifying/masking after the 8th digit, I.E only 8 digits need to be masked, I've tried doing it by hardcoding it by cropping the image as most of them are kinda similar, but the ones that are slightly off get messed up. Is there a way to stop tesseract masking these images after the 8th digit? I'm using cv2.rectangle to mask images.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "D:/Tess/tesseract.exe"


for imgfilepathactual in glob.iglob('D:/dataset/allpdf/data/*.jpeg'):
    
    imgfilepath2 = imgfilepathactual.split("/")[3]
    imgfilepath1 = imgfilepath2.split('\\')[1]
    imgfilepath = imgfilepath1.split(".")[0]
    #print(filepath)
    print(imgfilepath)
    

 
            
    img = cv2.imread('D:/dataset/allpdf/data/' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #if using with pdf conv
    #print(str(img))


    sobelX1 = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = 1)
    sobelY1 = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = 1)

    sobelX1 = np.uint8(np.absolute(sobelX1))
    sobelY1 = np.uint8(np.absolute(sobelY1))

    sobelCombined1 = cv2.bitwise_or(sobelX1, sobelY1)

    blurred = cv2.blur(sobelX1, (3,3)) #for pdf->img


    canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 5, 250)

    pts1 =np.argwhere(canny>0)
    y11,x11 = pts1.min(axis=0)
    y21,x21 = pts1.max(axis=0)

    cropped = img[y11:y21, x11:x21]
    #cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropped)
    resizedimage = cv2.resize(cropped, (1080, 720), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #actual 
    cv2.imwrite('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg', resizedimage)

    img = cv2.imread('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
    h1, w1, _= img.shape

   

    resizedimage = Image.open('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
    box1 = (0,0, w1, 0.90*h1)

    resizedimage = resizedimage.crop(box1)
    resizedimage.save('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')

    img = cv2.imread('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
    h2, w2, _ = img.shape

    print ((h2, w2), "reso")

    croppedimg2 = Image.open('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
    box2 = (0, 0.75*h2, 0.48*w2, h2)

    croppedimg2 = croppedimg2.crop(box2)
    croppedimg2.save('croppedimg2' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')

    aadharBoxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(croppedimg2, lang = "eng")#, config=' --psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    #adharBoxes = aadharBoxes[0:8]
    for b in aadharBoxes.splitlines():
        b = b.split(' ')
        high = []
        for i in range(8):
            b[i] = b[i].split(' ')
            high.append(int(b[i][2]))
            high.append(int(b[i][4]))
        #b = b[0:8]
        print(b)
        #print(len(b[0]))
        maskedImage = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[0][1]), np.min(high)), (int(b[7][3]), np.max(high)), (0, 0, 0), -1)
        cv2.imwrite("maskedImage" + imgfilepath + ".jpeg", maskedImage)
        pdf = img2pdf.convert("maskedImage"+ imgfilepath + ".jpeg")
        file = open("D:/dataset/allpdf/masked_files/masked" + imgfilepath + ".pdf", "wb")
        file.write(pdf)
        file.close()
    #else:
        #pdf = img2pdf.convert("unmaskedImage"+ resizedimage + ".jpeg")
        #file = open("D:/dataset/allpdf/masked_files/masked" + imgfilepath + ".pdf", "wb")
        #file.write(pdf)
        #file.close()
        
    os.remove('resizedimage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
    #os.remove('maskedImage' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
    #os.remove('croppedimg2' + imgfilepath + '.jpeg')
      


for filepathactual in glob.iglob('D:/dataset/allpdf/*.pdf'):
    #print(filepathactual)
    filepath2 = filepathactual.split("/")[2]
    filepath1 = filepath2.split("\\")[1]
    filepath = filepath1.split(".")[0]
    print(filepath)

    def convertPdf2img():
        pages = convert_from_path(filepathactual, 500)  #converting pdf to img
        for page in pages:
            page.save('out' + filepath + '.jpg', 'JPEG')


    
    convertPdf2img()
    


            
    img = cv2.imread('out' + filepath + '.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #if using with pdf conv



    sobelX1 = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = 1)
    sobelY1 = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = 1)

    sobelX1 = np.uint8(np.absolute(sobelX1))
    sobelY1 = np.uint8(np.absolute(sobelY1))

    sobelCombined1 = cv2.bitwise_or(sobelX1, sobelY1)

    blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3)) #for pdf->img


    canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 5, 250)

    pts1 =np.argwhere(canny>0)
    y11,x11 = pts1.min(axis=0)
    y21,x21 = pts1.max(axis=0)

    cropped = img[y11:y21, x11:x21]
    #cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropped)
    resizedimage = cv2.resize(cropped, (1080, 720), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #actual 
    cv2.imwrite('resizedimage' +filepath + '.jpeg', resizedimage)

    img = cv2.imread('resizedimage' +filepath + '.jpeg')
    h1, w1, _= img.shape

   

    resizedimage = Image.open('resizedimage' +filepath + '.jpeg')
    box1 = (0,0, w1, 0.90*h1)

    resizedimage = resizedimage.crop(box1)
    resizedimage.save('resizedimage' +filepath + '.jpeg')

    img = cv2.imread('resizedimage' +filepath + '.jpeg')
    h2, w2, _ = img.shape

    print ((h2, w2), "reso")

    croppedimg2 = Image.open('resizedimage' +filepath + '.jpeg')
    box2 = (0, 0.65*h2, 0.6*w2, h2)

    croppedimg2 = croppedimg2.crop(box2)
    croppedimg2.save('croppedimg2' + filepath + '.jpeg')

    aadharBoxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(croppedimg2, lang = "eng")

    for b in aadharBoxes.splitlines():
        b = b.split(' ')
        maskedImage = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[1]), h2 - int(b[2])), (int(b[3]), h2 - int(b[4])), (0, 0, 0), -1)
        #print(b, "coords")
        cv2.imwrite("maskedImage" + filepath + ".jpeg", maskedImage)
        pdf = img2pdf.convert("maskedImage"+ filepath + ".jpeg")
        file = open("D:/dataset/allpdf/masked_files/masked" + filepath + ".pdf", "wb")
        file.write(pdf)
        file.close()
        


    #print(w,h)
    os.remove('out' + filepath + '.jpg')
    os.remove('resizedimage' + filepath + '.jpeg')
    os.remove('maskedImage' + filepath + '.jpeg')
    os.remove('croppedimg2' + filepath + '.jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

To choice the first eight characters, those characters after the range would be blocked.

```
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('muTYX.jpg')

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

text = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img, lang = 'eng', config='--psm 7 --oem 3')

text = text.split('\n')
high = []
for i in range(8):
    text[i] = text[i].split(' ')
    high.append(int(text[i][2]))
    high.append(int(text[i][4]))

cv2.rectangle(img, (int(text[0][1]), np.min(high)), (int(text[7][3]), np.max(high)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('nubmer',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to use image_to_boxes if I want to mask, image_to_string doesnt help.
Also If I use this I get an error " maskedImage = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[1]), h2 - int(b[2])), (int(b[3]), h2 - int(b[4])), (0, 0, 0), -1)
IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I want to know what's your main problem, you need a mask crop your image? Or you want to use ```cv2.rectangle``` to label the first 8th character?(But not successful)

Comment: I  want to use cv2.rectangle to mask the first 8 characters in my image. 
apologies, I'm a newbie programmer.

Comment: @Nimish I have updated my code, try again.

Comment: Please upload your code and image completely, so I can figure out the problem.

Comment: I uploaded the code, can't upload the images as it contains sensitive info, ignore the box and cropping variables, I was using that as the hardcoded method

Comment: Added an image that is similar to the one I'm working on

Comment: So you still got an error : ```list index out of range```? Printing the value b to make sure it's not out of range.

Comment: Yes, still getting the same error, adding a snippet from my cmd.

(648, 1080) reso
['3', '244', '25', '276', '73', '0']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "withmask3.py", line 88, in <module>
    high.append(int(b[i][2]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You should spend some time on debug. The loop runs eight times, each times append two number, so it should be sixteen number in the array. It seems that  ```b``` only recognize three character.

Comment: Alright I'll look into that, I'll utilize the logic you provided and try and work it into what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: Not yet, I've been trying to play around with it but to no success, still trying it tho, as I said I'm kinda unexperienced as a programmer so this will take time haha.

Comment: I've figured it out finally, used a little different method but got it done